# Movie about the Earth being too hot to live on and everybody being underground

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I can't remember much, just a man walking out of a subway station or an underground parking lot with a space suit on, like the ones they use now for EVA. I remember that it was because the Earth was too hot and there was too much radiation, I think, to just walk the streets without protection, but he was in a big city and all the buildings were still standing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Early 2000 as I remember it how the movie was shot and the quality of how it look like maybe 90s

Comment: Just to be clear, did you actually watch this in the early 2000s, or is that just your guess as to when it was made? If you watched it later than that, then when? Also, did you watch it in English or another language? If another language, then what?

Comment: I'm guessing it's called *"The film with a really low budget, so the director just filmed very early in the morning to get empty streets and used a yellow filter over the lens to make it look post-apocalyptic"*. Starring Dean Cain, Michael Ironside and one of the ladies from Baywatch as the love interest.

Comment: I watched it in 2009 I think it was on TV then it was in English dubbing isn't really a thing here probably made in early 2000 or 90s if it was on TV then I just remember that scene the guy the space suit I have been looking for years for it didn't know a website like this exists

Comment: What color was that spacesuit? Was it shiny? Were there any weapons? Explosions? Was it dark in terms of colors?

Comment: It was white it was the same as the suits we have now the nasa tags where still on there only a little torn up